# Warning: substr() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

i got this error coming up when i try to display my latest tweets on the page.

The code on that line is:

```
$twitts = unserialize( base64_decode( $twitts ) );
foreach ($twitts as $twit) {
    ?>
    <p><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="<?php print esc_url('https://twitter.com/'.$twit->user->screen_name); ?>"><span>@<?php print esc_html($twit->user->screen_name); ?></span></a>
    <?php 
    $twit->text = substr(esc_html($twit->text), 0, $twitter_symbol_count); 
    print $twit->text . '...'; ?></p>
    <?php
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?!?! :(

Comment: Done! Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: `$twitter_symbol_count` is string and needs to be long. The error said what is the problem.

Comment: Hey Daniel, actually i'm a extra lame "coder", so if you'd be able to "chew it up for me, i'd be the most happy noob in the world! =)

Comment: update your question with the result of `var_dump($twitter_symbol_count);` to see what you have there.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code, like how you're setting `$twitter_symbol_count` ?

Comment: Heh, the vardump result = string(3) "yes". Also i edited my message to show more code

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is very clear. parameter 3 (`$twitter_symbol_count`) has to be long and it's string.

If you read here the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) you can see that parameter 2 & 3 are `int`.

If `$twitter_symbol_count` can be cast to `int` you can use this code:

```
$twit->text = substr(esc_html($twit->text), 0, intval($twitter_symbol_count));
```

Please update your question with `var_dump($twitter_symbol_count);` to give you an exact answer if this is not working.

**EDIT**

Your parameter `$twitter_symbol_count` must be something numeric. Can't be the `string` `"yes"`. What do you want to do here?

Comment: I tried the code you shared, and it helped me to switch to this error: Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in ...

Comment: As I suggest in my answer `$twitter_symbol_count` should be something numberic. From your `var_dump` it looks like it's the string "yes" so I don't know what exactly do you want to do here.

Comment: Kindly, i have no idea as this script is from a theme... It's supposed to display my tweets but it doesn't. All it does is giving me this error. As i searched the whole wp-content in my WordPress, i found this string only in this code.... That's terrific. I guess that's the limit of the characters for each tweet...

Comment: Yes. That parameter should be the limit. I don't know where you initialize `$twitter_symbol_count` with `yes` because it's not visible in your code. Search for this and probably you can fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
if(ctype_digit(trim($twitter_symbol_count)) || is_int($twitter_symbol_count))
{
    $twitter_symbol_count = (int)trim($twitter_symbol_count);
}
else
{
    $twitter_symbol_count = strlen(esc_html($twit->text));
}

$twit->text = 
    substr
    (
        esc_html
        (
            $twit->text
        ),
        0,
        $twitter_symbol_count
    );
```

Comment: Hey, tried your solution. And he comes up with "Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in ... ($twit->text = substr(esc_html($twit->text), 0, $twitter_symbol_count);"

Comment: Just dumbly deleted ($twit->text = substr(esc_html($twit->text), 0, $twitter_symbol_count);. Just blank space :D

Comment: @DimaGudesk See my edit. Your error message should give you a line number and that line number is your issue. Anyways, if I solved your original issue then feel free to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: OH, it actually changed a little bit.  Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/35/468327/webspace/siteapps/WordPress-97676/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/nrgevent-plugins/composer/shortcodes/nrgevent_contact_google_maps.php on line 281 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/35/468327/webspace/siteapps/WordPress-97676/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/nrgevent-plugins/composer/shortcodes/nrgevent_contact_google_maps.php on line 292